# Python Selenium get URL doesn't load

Tags: python, selenium

Hi I'm pretty new to selenium and I'm trying to open different links in a for loop but `driver.get` sends the URL to the bar but without loading. This happens only for the link in the for loop, not the first one. I have tried to look for a couple of similar Qs but I'm not sure what am I doing wrong

```
    class RunGCTest():
        def test(self):
            driver_location = x
            os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = driver_location
            driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_location)
            driver.implicitly_wait(30)
            driver.get("https://test.com/")

                import csv
                with open
                 ....

                for abc in range(len(xyz)):
               
                 driver.get("https://test.com/page="+xyz[abc][1])

ChromeTest = RunGCTest()
ChromeTest.test()
```

Comment: What's with the prefix `"URL"` in `"URL"+xyz[abc][1]`?

Comment: as www.example.com/page=1
page 2 
etc

So Im just concatenating the page number to the URL

Comment: But you're concatenating to a (constant) string `"URL"` when you perhaps meant to prefix with a variable. Please update your code accordingly as the above would obviously not work.

Comment: its just a URL with pages and Im concatenating the 1st constant part of the URL with iteration list of the pages numbers

Comment: Which get is it failing on? What's the error message?

Comment: there is no error message, the URL appears in the URL Bar without loading.
It loads when I press Enter manually

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to wait for the page to load completely before looping to the next custom URL. Try out below code snippet:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
class RunGCTest():

        def wait_for_page_load(self):
            WebDriverWait(self.driver, config.wait).until(
                lambda driver: driver.execute_script('return document.readyState') == 'complete')

        def test(self):
            driver_location = x
            os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = driver_location
            driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_location)
            driver.get("http://URL 1/")

                import csv
                with open
                 ....

                for abc in range(len(xyz)):
               
                 driver.get("URL"+xyz[abc][1])
                 wait_for_page_load()

ChromeTest = RunGCTest()
ChromeTest.test()
```

Hope that this will resolve your query.

Thanks,

Comment: driver.implicitly_wait(30)
Im already doing that but still isn't loading

Comment: Could you please double check manually if hitting those custom direct URLs are working as expected first. Because it should work theoretically per the existing code.

Comment: When I press Enter the URL Loads, but Im not sure how Send Enter after driver.get

Comment: `driver.get("https://test.com/page="+xyz[abc][1])`
Tried that but still not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227556/discussion-between-panchdev-and-ryan).